# CSS rule is not affecting HTML

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap v.3 and I wanted to make a diferrent button, so I copy all the css classes for `btn-primary`, renamed to myBigButton and apply my changes. [Here](http://www.bootply.com/1CIxybfdnB) works perfect. However in my page the new class 'myBigButton' doesnt exist (when I inspect element from the broswer..)
I have the same code in my page

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-4">               
            <button type="button" class="btn myBigBtn btn-block ">aaaaaa</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">               
            <button type="button" class="btn myBigBtn btn-block">bbbbbb</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">               
            <button type="button" class="btn myBigBtn btn-block">cccccc</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

any ideas why?

The strangest is that if double write the css class

```
.myBigBtn {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #5A6E9E;
    border-color:#5A6E9E;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 23px;
}

.myBigBtn {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #5A6E9E;
    border-color:#5A6E9E;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 23px;
}
```

works..

**UPDATE**

I add all the css file [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1oqajcw9/1/) where it doesn't work either..

Comment: cross check your css file, I suspect it might be causing because of any closing bracket "}"

Comment: Can be a cache issue? How are you including you css class?

Comment: include your css top of the bootstrap or using `!important` or clear browser catch

Comment: Always ensure yourself that your customize.css files are included after (below) the default bootstrap.css file.

Comment: Where is your page at?

Comment: Sounds like you have a typo in your css above the first class - like Nilesh says, there may be a missing closing curly brace. Can you copy your whole css file into the bootply

Comment: Well.. I double checked I don't have any  missing closing curly brace.

I add the css class at the end of the existing boostap.css

Comment: parse error or missing closing comment?

Comment: @Pete i just update the question with all the css...

Comment: do you actually have this line in: `//here is my class`?  comments in css should be done like this: `/* I am a comment */`

Comment: oh my GOD... yes... that's was the reason.... Submit an answer to take the credits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the comment:

```
//here is my class
```

Comments in css are done like this

```
/* here is my class */
```

Change the comment to this and it should work

Answer (score 1):

Everything works fine!

Include your CSS file in the `<head>` **after** the Bootstrap CSS:

```
...
<head>
    Bootstrap CSS
    Custom CSS
</head>
...
```

**HTML** should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>BOOTSTRAP TEMPLATE</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body id="body">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button type="button" class="btn myBigBtn btn-block ">aaaaaa</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button type="button" class="btn myBigBtn btn-block">bbbbbb</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button type="button" class="btn myBigBtn btn-block">cccccc</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The custom CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
```

It's **good practice** to link to an **external CSS file**.

Comment: It works indeed.. However I am curious why it doesn't worked when i added in the same .css

Comment: At the end there is `.myBigBtn .badge`. What means class `.badge` in `.myBigBtn`. What you want is **only** `.myBigBtn` !

Answer (score -1):

.myBigBtn and .btn have same prioprity, so styles are applied in order css files are included to page. And so .btn override your styles. That's the most probable cause.

Comment: Actually, as the `.myBigBtn` is declared after the bootstrap style, it should take precedence if it is the same level of specifity

Comment: You don't understand..... `class="btn myBigBtn btn-block"` this doesnt matter at all. `<link href="bootstrap.css"><link href="my.css">` vs `<link href="my.css"><link href="bootstrap.css">` this does.

Comment: *You* don't understand: the custom styles are included **after** the bootstrap styles so `.myBigBtn` will be decalred **after** `.btn` and therefore will override `.btn`.  In your comment above, the first version will work, the second will not: http://jsfiddle.net/2ubwzurn/

Comment: Yes, 1st is correct. 2nd isn't. And how you could possibly know how author includes his css styles until he mentioned it?

Comment: Look at the bootply link in the question

Comment: And? `/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */` is default comment when creating new bootply.

Comment: How about the fact that OP says they include the style twice and it works - obviously points to some sort of parse error above the first style rather than an ordering issue